# Ubuntu Server Doesn't see Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have 64-bit Ubuntu Server 19.10 installed on my Rasberry Pi 4B with 4GB RAM. I also have the GUI desktop installed. The RP 4 uses Bluetooth 5.0 which the Raspbian OS can use but Ubuntu doesn't see Bluetooth installed. Is there a patch to let Ubuntu use the RP 4's on-board Bluetooth adapter?

```
tom@ubuntu:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:8505 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[   12.336503] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.336556] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.336568] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.336575] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.336590] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   41.499813] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   41.499819] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   41.499831] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
tom@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: @Tom why did you use a different account for the edit?

Comment: I originally used my Windows machine to ask the question then, in order to be able to copy and paste the output requested, I used Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi. I'm back on my Windows machine to post this reply. I use the machines interchangeably until I get the Pi working just the way I want it, which includes access to Bluetooth.

Comment: @TomL12953 in that case I suggest that you use https://askubuntu.com/contact to request a merge of your accounts .